# Rendering x3d indexedfacset with ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, x3d

I using x3d in an ember cli framework. In an older version of the ember framework everything runs well. I updated ember.js lately. After the ember.js update it is no problem to display idexedfaceset or indexedlineset in the x3d scene from the start of the ember application. But now there is a problem to add idexedfaceset or indexedlineset to the scene after the application is completely loaded. For example see the code below. If the display value is set to true by clicking a button the application throw an error:
*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getPoints' of null at 
x3dom.registerNodeType.defineClass.nodeChanged.nodeChanged (x3dom-full.js:4596)*

I understand the error indicates that the coordinate tag is missing in this moment where x3d detect a node is added and try to render it. Afterwards I check the html code and the coordinate tag is where it should be. But the element isn't displayed in the x3d scene. It seems there is a short delay by adding the coordinate tag.
I know it is possible to display the element by using a jquery commad like $("#scene").append("..."). But I would like to use the ember behavior because i do a lot more like calculating positions and dimensions.
I would be happy if someone could help to solve the problem. Thanks a lot.

````
//application.hbs
{{#if this.display}}
  <transform>
    <shape def="" ispickable="0" bboxsize="-1,-1,-1" bboxcenter="0,0,0" render="true">
      <appearance sorttype="auto" alphaclipthreshold="0.1">
        <material specularcolor="0,0,0" shininess="0.2" emissivecolor="0,0,0" ambientintensity="0.2" transparency="0.5" diffusecolor="0 0 1">
        </material>
      </appearance>
      <indexedfaceset ccw="true" colorpervertex="false" colorindex=" 0 0 0 0" coordindex="0 3 2 1 0" solid="true" usegeocache="true" lit="true" normalpervertex="true" normalupdatemode="fast" convex="true" >

        <coordinate point="-1 0 0, -1 1 0, 1 1 0, 1 0 0"></coordinate>

        <color color="0 0 1"></color>
      </indexedfaceset>
    </shape>
  </transform>
{{/if}} ```
````

Comment: do you think you could make an ember-twiddle or a small github repo that reproduces this specific issue? I don't think enough has been shared currently to answer your question. My knee-jerk reaction, though, is that you may want to run your dom-interacting code (ie whatever you do to initialize `x3d`) after `if` block renders it's internal block once `this.display` changes. You can achieve this by scheduling a function to be executed `afterRender` via specific run loop queues https://guides.emberjs.com/release/applications/run-loop/

Comment: I created a gitlab repo with a minimum ember application that should show the problem: [link](https://gitlab.com/sheft/x3drender)

Comment: I ran the project but do not see any errors. could you please update the README and explain what should be happening and exactly how to reproduce the problems :)

Comment: The README is updated. I hope the explanation is in sufficient detail. Otherwise just ask again. Many thanks!

Comment: Is there something special that I need to do in order to make x3d actually render the shape? I download the project, run `npm install` or `yarn install` -> `ember serve` -> navigate to `http:127.0.0.1:4200/`. I see no shapes in my up to date chrome as well as no errors. The x3d element rendered as a `.`

Comment: There should be nothing to do. I cleaned up the project and updated the repo again. How it should look like you can see at [http://embertest.tagnix.de](http://embertest.tagnix.de)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your latest changes finally allowed me to run the project. When researching your problem, I found a [similar issue](https://github.com/x3dom/x3dom/issues/361)

> As far as I can tell, it has nothing to do with d3 or jquery and has
>   everything to do with appending the indexed set before appending the
>   coordinate using DOM functions which affect both d3 and jquery.
>   Appending the coordinate to the indexed set and then appending the
>   indexed set to the rest of the DOM should work fine.

Another commenter noted

> For me, the node isn’t there yet, since I am creating DOM from JSON.
>   The solution was to build the child node first, then add it to the
>   parent, then add the parent. Before that, the code would die in the
>   appendChild.

The Ember rendering layer has changed a lot from Ember 1.x -> Ember 3.x. It seems to me that a change in the order in which nodes are built/appended to the DOM has caused this issue for you since x3dom is expecting one order and ember another.

The first quick solution to your current issue here would be to avoid wrapping `<transform>` elements in `{{#if}}` blocks for hiding / showing since this removes / readds to the DOM in a way that `x3dom` is unaware of. Rather, control the visibility by using the `x3dom` [render](https://doc.x3dom.org/author/Grouping/Transform.html) property

```
<transform render="{{if this.display "true" "false"}}">
  <shape def="" ispickable="0" bboxsize="-1,-1,-1" bboxcenter="0,0,0" render="true">
    <appearance sorttype="auto" alphaclipthreshold="0.1">
      <material specularcolor="0,0,0" shininess="0.2" emissivecolor="0,0,0" ambientintensity="0.2" transparency="0.5" diffusecolor="0 0 1">
      </material>
    </appearance>
    <indexedfaceset ccw="true" colorpervertex="false" colorindex=" 0 0 0 0" coordindex="0 1 2 3 0" solid="true" usegeocache="true" lit="true" normalpervertex="true" normalupdatemode="fast" convex="true" >

        <coordinate point="-2 -2 0, 0 -2 0, 0 0 0, -2 0 0"></coordinate>

      <color color="0 0 1"></color>
    </indexedfaceset>
  </shape>
</transform>
```

Alternatively, you will need to also avoid wrapping the `<transform>` in `{{#if}}` and use the `x3dom` API directly via javascript in an `@action`.

Answer (score 0):

It’s very interesting to know, that the other posts are from 2014/2015. Since July 2015 I work on these topic and so far every thing runs well. It was no problem to generate the x3d scene with several ember components and without updating ember. ;) 
I expected some changes with the ember update. I suspect the same like you that the order in which nodes are built/appended to the DOM has changed.
For my default scene I use the the render attribute to hide and showing elements from now.
Everything else I will hide and show by using the x3dom API via javascript in an @action until there is another solution.
It’s a pity that I can’t use ember componets as before because I think they are made for creating individual tags. Many thanks for your efforts.

Comment: the best way to show thanks is to accept my answer :)